# variable changing value unexpectedly only when equal to zero in MASM32

Tags: arrays, variables, assembly, masm, masm32

I recently got arrays working in masm32, but I'm running into a very confusing snag. I have a procedure (`AddValue`) that accepts one argument and adds that argument to an element in an array called `bfmem`. Which element to affect is determined by a variable called `index`. However, `index` appears to be changing its value where i would not expect it to.

If `index` is greater than 0, the program behaves normally. However, if `index` equals 0, its value will be changed to whatever value was passed to the procedure. This is utterly baffling to me, especially as this only happens when `index` is set to zero. I don't know much MASM so forgive me if this is a really simple problem.

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none
include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

.data
bfmem dd 0 dup(30000)
index dd 0
_output db 10 dup(0)

.code

AddValue proc val                          ; adds val to bfmem[index]

     invoke dwtoa, index, addr _output
     invoke StdOut, addr _output           ;prints '0' (as expected)

     mov ecx, index                        ;mov index to register for arithmatic
     mov eax, val                          ;mov val to register for arithmatic
     add [ecx * 4 + bfmem], eax            ;multiply index by 4 for dword
                                           ;then add to array to get the element's                  
                                           ;memory address, and add value

     invoke dwtoa, index, addr _output
     invoke StdOut, addr _output           ;prints '72' (not as expected)

     ret

AddValue endp    


main:
     mov index, 0
     invoke AddValue, 72 


     invoke StdIn, addr _output, 1
     invoke ExitProcess, 0

end main
```

The only thing I can think of is that the assembler is doing some kind of arithmetic optimization (noticing ecx is zero and simplifying the `[ecx * 4 + bfmem]` expression in some way that changes the output). If so, how can I fix this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: push [bfmem] - add [ecx * 4 + bfmem], eax - pop [bfmem] would protect the value if that's what the  problem is

Comment: Don't do the push/pop. You're only masking the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your declaration:

```
bfmem dd 0 dup(30000)
```

Says to allocate 0 bytes initialized with the value 30000. So when `index` is 0, you are overwriting the value of `index` (the address of `index` and `bfmem` coincide). Larger indexes you don't see the problem because you're overwriting other memory, like your output buffer. If you want to test to see that this is what's happening, try this:

```
bfmem dd 0 dup(30000)
index dd 0
_messg dd "Here is an output message", 13, 10, 0
```

Run your program with an `index` value of 1, 2, 3 and then display the message (`_messg`) using `invoke StdOut...`. You'll see that it overwrites parts of the message.

I assume you meant:

```
bfmem  dd 30000 dup(0)
```

Which is 30000 bytes initialized to 0.

Comment: Wow, idiot move on my part. Yes, I mixed up my size and value for the declaration. Never would have though to look there; thanks a lot!

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart no problem. It's hard to see the forest for the trees sometimes, which is why it's good to have someone else look at it.:)